# Simplify deserializing an object using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I have JSON which looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Example 1",
        "player_class": 2,
        "player_class_name": "Class1",
        "url": "/someurl",
        "standard_ccp_signature_core": {
          "as_of": "2019-07-04T16:46:23.760Z",
          "format": 2,
          "components": [ 742, 51779, 51790, 503, 52810, 52819, 381, 49164, 48886, 56223 ]
        },
        "wild_ccp_signature_core": null
    }
]
```

The generated class looks like the following:

```cs
public class Archetype 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string player_class_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("standard_ccp_signature_core")]
    public StandardCcpSignatureCore core_cards { get; set; }
}

public class StandardCcpSignatureCore 
{
    public List<int> components { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to simplify the `Archetype` class a little so that it looks like this:

```cs
public class Archetype 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int player_class { get; set; }
    public string player_class_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("standard_ccp_signature_core")]
    public List<int> components { get; set; }  
}
```

Is this possible using the Newtonsoft deserializer?  I am pretty sure I have to setup a `JsonObject` attribute on the components property of my `Archetype` class, but am unsure of how to tell it how to do this.

Comment: Could you just add in an additonal property? "public List<int> components { get { return core_cards.components; } set { core_cards.components = value; } }". Obviously not a great solution if it's a very large object you're trying to avoid keeping/parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following converter:

```
public class ArchetypeConverter : JsonConverter
{ 
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Archetype).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var token = obj.SelectToken("standard_ccp_signature_core.components");

        if (token != null)
            obj.Add(token.Parent);

        using (reader = obj.CreateReader())
        {
            existingValue = (existingValue ?? new Archetype());
            serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
        }
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ArchetypeConverter))]
public class Archetype
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int player_class { get; set; }
    public string player_class_name { get; set; }
    public List<int> components { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [generic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) version of converter?

Comment: Why not. If it's necessary you can create a generic version of convert and specify the path through an attribute.